# Using Python Variables in one Instance

Tags: python, variables

What I am trying to accomplish is simply using a second variable in my "scanjob" variable adding "api_tok". I am using a product that needs an api_token for every call so I just want to persistently add "api_tok" where needed. So far

```
auths = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:443', auth=('admin', 'blahblah'), headers = heads)
api_tok = {'api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'}
scanjob = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?%s'  % (api_tok))
scanjob.url
u"http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?set(['api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'])"
```

as you can see from scanjob.url, its adding a "set" after the "?". Why? If I could remove that "set" my call will work. I tried many different variants of combining a string such as:

```
scanjob = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?%s' + api_tok)
scanjob.url
u"http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?set(['api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'])"
scanjob = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?' + str(api_tok))
scanjob.url
u"http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?set(['api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'])"
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{....}` is syntax to produce a [*set* object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> As of Python 2.7, non-empty sets (not `frozensets`) can be created by placing a comma-separated list of elements within braces, for example: `{'jack', 'sjoerd'}`, in addition to the `set` constructor.

For example:

```
>>> {'api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'}
set(['api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'])
>>> {'jack', 'sjoerd'}
set(['jack', 'sjoerd'])
```

This is where your mystery `set([...])` text comes from.

You just wanted to produce a string here:

```
api_tok = 'api_token=e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'
scanjob = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1?%s'  % api_tok)
```

Alternatively, tell `requests` to add the query parameters with the `params` keyword argument, passing in a dictionary:

```
parameters = {'api_token': 'e27e901c196b8f0399bc79'}
scanjob = requests.get('http://10.0.0.127:4242/scanjob/1', params=parameters)
```

This has the added advantage that `requests` now is responsible for properly encoding the query parameters.